# How can i remove the milliseconds from date time in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I have to compare the date in rails to get the values after that date I have send the date as `"2013-03-04T06:26:25Z"`but actually the record in the db contains date as follows `2013-03-04 06:26:25.817149` so when i check with the date it also returns that record but i want records after that date. how can i remove the milliseconds from the db? please help me.

Comment: which DB are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres....

Comment: Or if you know that the time you're using to search with never has millisecond precision, just improve your query and query for records `>= time+1.second`.

Answer (score 61):

I had a similar problem

Update your time object like this before sending it to the database :

```
time.change(:usec => 0)
```

Comment: Cant we be able to specify the format to save instead of doing this?

Comment: The format to save is defined in your database, it can be DATE, DATETIME, etc. Your ORM will convert the date to the right format for you. I don't know postgres, so maybe you can change the type to a less precise one.

Comment: No i am asking about setting some thing like strftime(%H%M%S) somewhere in the config so as to make the date to be saved as specified format.

Comment: You don't have to deal with the time format because your ORM does it. See about datatypes in postgres.

Comment: Microseconds matter, esp. when you're testing. The database might truncate microseconds to predefined precision, e.g. Postgres makes it 6. Thus the value read back from the database **does not** match the value it was back in Ruby land, and you get a mismatch like: `-:completed_at => 2018-07-30 12:27:06.544967008 +0000, +:completed_at => 2018-07-30 12:27:06.544967000 +0000`. Easiest of all is to remove microseconds in values we're about to store. Then matching is okay and we don't have to work around this truncation issue.

Answer (score 33):

Since ruby 1.9 you can use `round`

```
t = Time.now.round
t.usec # => 0
```

Comment: `.round` _rounds_, it doesn't just remove the millis. So in the OP example, you'd get `06:26:25 != 06:26:26`

Answer (score 6):

I was also having this problem, however when I was applying the change [as indicated in @Intrepidd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15199496/1454953), it wasn't affecting the microseconds of my time object.

Please note that (at least currently) the `:usec` key only works with the [`Time#change`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change) method, and **not** with the [`DateTime#change`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-change) method.

The `DateTime#change` method ignores the keys that it doesn't accept, so you wouldn't be able to tell that your attempted change of the microseconds didn't work unless you inspected the object further (such as with `DateTime#rfc3339(9)`).

So before you attempt this change, make sure that you are working with a `Time` object, not a `DateTime` object.